# How to access your SQLite tables through ContenProvider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

So I have been doing research in order to switch my `super(Context context, Cursor cursor)` deprecated `CursorAdapter` code to the `LoaderManager` and `CursorLoader` code. I am very close, but stuck with one last thing. What kind of `URI` do I need to access the SQLite tables that I have? I am new to `ContentProviders`, so please bear with me on that front. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use following URI

```
Uri.parse("content://packagename/tablename");
```

Moreover you have to use following lines in onCreate()

```
 cr = getContentResolver();
 ContentProviderClient cpc = cr.acquireContentProviderClient(uri);
```

The above snippet will work when you want to use User Defined Content Privoder

Answer (score 0):

> What kind of URI do I need to access the SQLite tables that I have?

You need to write a `ContentProvider`. As part of writing that `ContentProvider`, you will decide for yourself what you want your `Uri` to look like (beyond the mandatory `content://` scheme). That `Uri` will be the combination of the scheme, your chosen unique authority string, and an optional path:

```
`content://your.authority.goes.here/anything/else/is/optional`
```

The Android developer documentation contains [instructions for creating a `ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html).

Comment: hmm, so there is no built in one? I will check it out. Thank you

Comment: So currently I have a Database helper that creates everything for me. But its not part of a ContentProvider. If I use a ContentProvider, which looks to be my only choice to not use deprecated code, should I move all my DatabseHelper stuff into a ContentProvider to do the work there? Or should I just have an empty onCreate and just use the ContentProvider to do queries with ContentProvide?

Comment: @Andy: "which looks to be my only choice to not use deprecated code" -- nonsense. Use `AsyncTask` to move work to the background and use `ContentResolver` for the queries (along with the inserts, updates, etc.). "should I move all my DatabseHelper stuff into a ContentProvider to do the work there?" -- your `SQLiteOpenHelper` probably could be an inner class of the `ContentProvider`, though I have not tried that. "Or should I just have an empty onCreate and just use the ContentProvider to do queries with ContentProvide?" -- you lost me there.